# Are the CORINE Landcover datasets available by country?

Tags: shapefile, land-cover, europe

I found the overall dataset for Europe but it is a huge file for my computer to run. I would like to have a shapefile for the Netherlands specifically.

http://land.copernicus.eu/pan-european/corine-land-cover/clc-2012/view

Hope you can help

Comment: Add a link where you found your dataset. That would help others with haunting.

Comment: Corine data come from European Environment Agency (EEA), search there.